# Unable to use Sea Glass LAF for the Java application

Tags: java, look-and-feel, seaglass

I am trying to use the Sea Glass LAF for a Java application but it gives the **Class Not Found Exception** (in Windows using JDK 8). I added the **seaglass-0.1.7.3 jar** file to the libraries folder and added it to build path. I also added `import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;` to the code but it is shown as an unused import.

Below is my code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel" );
                setHomeWindow( new HomeWindow() );
                window.getFrame().setVisible( true );

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

[image: Here is the stack trace:]

How can I solve this and use Seaglass? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code and it works fine. I downloaded the seaglass jar from this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseaglasslookandfeel02jar.htm

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class HomeWindow extends JFrame{

    public HomeWindow() {
        setTitle("look and feel demo");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);       
    }

        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel" );
                         new HomeWindow();                      

                    }
                    catch ( Exception e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } );
        }


}
```

Comment: I tested the above code with seaglass 0.1.7.3 from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseaglasslookandfeel02jar.htm and I encountered the same error as you. Try do download the 0.2 seaglass jar version and it will work.

Comment: Changing the jar version solved it, thanks :) However unfortunately card panels do not work well when Sea Glass is used.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be the case that the SynthUI pluggable-look-and-feel classes (on which the Sea Glass LAF depends) were migrated from the `sun.*` package space into `javax.*` as of Java 7. As mentioned in a comment by @aurelianr, a newer Sea Glass JAR that has been compiled against JDK >= 7 should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

@thewmo and @aurelianr are right.
You may find the newest version here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.seaglasslookandfeel/seaglasslookandfeel

If you want to do it using `Maven` or simple downloading the `jar file`

Comment: I downloaded 0.2.1 from this link, and still get NoClassDefFound on sun/swing/plaf/synth/SynthIcon.

Any thoughts?